# Taking a dictionary from a text file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary stored inside a text file called 'Dict.txt' like so:

```
[{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 15: 0}]
```

I've got some code to take this file, and turn it into a dictionary:

```
import json, ast

file = open('Dict.txt', 'r')
save = file.read()
file.close()
for func in (ast.literal_eval, json.loads):
    file = func(save)
file = file[0]
```

But when I run the code, I get the error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

I'm not used to working with dictionaries, json, or ast. So I do know why this is happening, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not valid JSON because the outermost structure is a list, not a dict and the keys are numbers rather than strings. You can still use literal_eval like this:

```
file = open('Dict.txt', 'r')
your_list_with_a_dict = ast.literal_eval(file.read())
your_dict = your_list_with_a_dict[0]
file.close()
```

Comment: This worked, but if I have an array, it only opens the first item. How would I do this?

Comment: your_list_with_a_dict[0] takes only the first item out. What would you like to do with the rest of the items? You can also just use the result of `ast.literal_eval(file.read())`, it's all in there.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was just wondering, what do you mean by 'trust the input'?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `literal_eval` when you read the data from your file. So, you can simply do this:

Content of `test.txt`:

```
[{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 15: 0}]
```

Code reading the file and outputting in desired data-structure:

```
from ast import literal_eval
data = []
with open('test.txt') as a:
    data = literal_eval(a.read())
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 0, 15: 0}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expression is your best friend :)

```
import re
import ast
file = open('dict.txt', 'r')
save = file.read()
file.close()
result = re.search('\[(.*)\]',save)
my_dict = result.group(1)
print my_dict
my_dict = ast.literal_eval(my_dict)
print type(my_dict)
print my_dict
```